# Android Inject touch events on other applications

Tags: android, touch-event, android-backup-service

I want to create an application which injects touch event out of my application. Simple one like touch on `posX,posY` in every 5 seconds (timer).

I've just created an app which works on my `activity` only.

Here is the code which performs touch event.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                m_Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, posX, posY, 0));
                m_Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,posX, posY, 0));
            }
        }).start();
```

Then I just added `INJECT_EVENTS` permission in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"></uses-permission>
```

I also made my application as a system app by changing it's root to `/system/app`

When I run my app it works fine by touching on `posX` and `posY` once in a sec. But when I draw navigation bar or just try to minimize my app it closes unfortunately with an error.

```
injecting to another application requires inject_events permission
```

Please help me to solve this problem or if you have any test projects send me.
Thanks.

Comment: Does logcat show that the app is granted the permission when it's started? Also, are you running on a fairly recent cookie, like L? Do you have a /system/priv-app/ folder on your device? How do you sign your app? INJECT_EVENTS has the signature protection level: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

Comment: I just moved my apk to folder system/app. I'm trying on Android Kitkat. No logcat doesn't show that app is granted the permission. If I'm doing anything wrong can you explain how to make my app system application?